# Photo album of 20 people in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a photo album on python. And chose 20 people.

I have a menu where there is a List where we select a person and 2 buttons: Album and List.

[image: Menu]

I choose a person and click on the "Album" button.

After pressing the "Album" button, I get a photo album in which all photos except the selected one are arranged in a circle, and in the center is the selected photo of the selected person.

[image: Album]

And in the List button a list of photos with the signature appears.[image: List]

I managed to take this 20 photos, but then I got stuck. How to select a photo by name and put it in the center of the circle. And how to insert photos into a circle, and the selected photo is placed in the middle? And where is the list of photos, I don't understand how to put names next to the photo?

This is what I stuffed

```
# Libraries
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import PIL

# Create a window
root = Tk ()
root.title ("Photo Album")
root.geometry ("550x250")


my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("1.jpg"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("2.jpg"))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("3.jpg"))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("4.jpg"))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("5.jpg"))
my_img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("6.jpg"))
my_img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("7.jpg"))
my_img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("8.jpg"))
my_img9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("9.jpg"))
my_img10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("10.jpg"))
my_img11 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("11.jpg"))
my_img12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("12.jpg"))
my_img13 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("13.jpg"))
my_img14 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("14.jpg"))
my_img15 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("15.jpg"))
my_img16 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("16.jpg"))
my_img17 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("17.jpg"))
my_img18 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("18.jpg"))
my_img19 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("19.jpg"))
my_img20 = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ("20.jpg"))


image_list = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg",
          "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg",
          "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg",
          "13.jpg", "14.jpg", "15.jpg", "16.jpg"
          "17.jpg", "18.jpg", "19.jpg", "20.jpg"]

name_list = ["Tom Stark", "Spider man", "Tor",
         "Groot", "Black Widow", "Hulk",
         "Jon Snow", "Eddard Stark", "Tyrion Lannister",
         "Gandalf", "Rick", "Morty",
         "Mozart", "Bach", "Vivaldi",
         "Mahler", "Black Panther", "Arthas",
         "Illidan", "Thrall"]

imgs = [PIL.Image.open (i) for i in image_list]


# command for "List of people"
def wind1 ():
    window = tk.Toplevel ()
    window.images = []
    min_shape = sorted ([(np.sum (i.size), i.size) for i in imgs]) [0] [1]
    for i in imgs:
      i = i.resize (min_shape)
      window.images.append (ImageTk.PhotoImage (i))
      my_label = Label (window, image = window.images [-1])
      my_label.pack (pady = 10)

# command for "Background"
def wind2 ():
    window = tk.Toplevel ()
    label = tk.Label (window, text = "FON")
    label.pack ()


# "People List" button
spisok = Button (text = "Guest List", padx = "20", pady = "10", command = wind1)
spisok.place (x = 300, y = 20)

# "Background" button
fon = Button (text = "Background", padx = "20", pady = "10", command = wind2)
fon.place (x = 440, y = 20)

# window display
root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: i haven't worked on tkinter yet, but i suggest you to make a function or class for common tasks, like by providing image path have 20 photos object through a function which when you interact with tkinter  you can add them

Comment: create a class that sorts images, and puts the chosen one in the middle. you're gonna have to work out the co-ordinates though

Comment: is there a simplified way to display images in a circle?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions in one, please try to edit your question and focus on a single problem. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)